# OAuth認証でDBに保存したアクセストークンを使ってログインできるのでしょうか？

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

OAuth認証を使ってTwitterへログインしようとしています．使用しているライブラリはTwitterOAuthです．

OAuth認証の流れ，ネット上に上がっているプログラムは分かったのですが，疑問が生まれました．

アクセストークンを取得して，それをDBに保存して，2回目以降はそのアクセストークンを利用してログインするということはできないのでしょうか？やはりcallbackが必要になるのでしょうか？また，その場合，DBにアクセストークンを保存しておく必要性はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/faq

> How long does an access token last? 
>   We do not currently expire access tokens

公式FAQによればアクセストークンに有効期限は設けてないとの
ことです。
ですのでアクセストークンとアクセストークンシークレットをDBに保存しておけば
再度そのアクセストークンとアクセストークンシークレットでログインできます。